# Remove object from array with a nested property in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array:

```
var myArray = [{state: {name: 'object #1'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #2'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #3'}}];
```

I'm trying to remove with lodash the object where `state.name` is *'object #1'*. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
_.remove(myArray, {
        name: 'object #1'
    });
```

But it's not working. Initially I tried it like this, which for me is the more obvious way of doing it:

```
_.remove(myArray, {
        state.name: 'object #1'
    });
```

But it didn't worked either and my JS validator complained about the dot notation in there.

How do you do this in lodash?

Comment: It's because in JS: **`{} !== {}`**!

Comment: I've provided you an answer containing pure js solution. Even two solutions.

Comment: @arielcr Is requirement to remove an element from an existing array as described at original Question _"Remove object from array with a nested property"_, or create a new array where specific elements are not included at new array?

Comment: @guest271314 the idea is to remove an element from the array

Comment: @arielcr You can use `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove element from an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_.remove` takes a predicate function.
You can do it this way:

```
_.remove(myArray, function(arg) {
    return arg.name == 'object #1';
});
```

Comment: The predicate function must return something! In your case the returned value for all the items will be `undefined` which means the array will be empty afterwards as all its items have been removed!

Comment: Thanks @ibrahimmahrir!

Answer (score 3):

In pure js, using `Array#filter`.

```js
var myArray = [{state: {name: 'object #1'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #2'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #3'}}];

    myArray = myArray.filter(v => v.state.name != 'object #1');
    console.log(myArray);
```

or using `Array#forEach`.

```js
var myArray = [{state: {name: 'object #1'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #2'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #3'}}],
    newArr = [];
    myArray.forEach(v => v.state.name !== 'object #1' ? newArr.push(v) : null);
    console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Do approaches at `javascript` at Answer remove element from existing array, or create new array where an element of existing array is not included?

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, was thinking about it, but I'm not sure that it's a good idea to modify the original obj :C

Comment: That is requirement at text of OP "Remove object from array with a nested property"?

Comment: @guest271314 Well, it's not precised exactly. You can remove an object from array without mutating it or with.

Comment: The text of original Question is precise from perspective here; remove specific y from x is different from create new x without specific y.

Comment: @guest271314 You have asked OP for it, so I guess that you are not fully confident about it... Lets wait for OP reply then, but please don't accuse me for ignorance...

Comment: Confidence has nothing to do with the context. The plain language is clear. If OP intends to adjust the clear meaning of the text at original Question, that would probably be helpful; if requirement is not in fact to remove an element from an existing array, as compared to creating a new array without specific element. As the text currently appears, the requirement is not ambiguous. Do not make accusations. Have no issues with direct communication, here. Agreed, perhaps OP will chime in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash [reject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject) with a [matchesProperty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#matchesProperty) shorthand.

```
var result = _.reject(myArray, ['state.name', 'object #1']);
```

```js
var myArray = [{
    state: {
      name: 'object #1'
    }
  },
  {
    state: {
      name: 'object #2'
    }
  },
  {
    state: {
      name: 'object #3'
    }
  }
];

var result = _.reject(myArray, ['state.name', 'object #1']);

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AdamBoduch unfortunately `remove` mutates the array, while `reject` doesn't.

Comment: Completely agree with you. I'd use `reject()` myself for immutability. Thought I'd mention it since `remove()` was the function in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback of [`_.remove`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) like this:

```
_.remove(myArray, function(o) {
    return o.name === 'object #1';
});
```

or shortly using **arrow functions** like this:

```
_.remove(myArray, o => o.name === 'object #1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use lodash, when you can do it in plan JS?

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(element) {
  return element.state.name !== 'object #1';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is to remove an element from an existing array, you can use `Array.prototype.splice()`, `Array.prototype.findIndex()`

```js
var myArray = [{state: {name: 'object #1'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #2'}},
               {state: {name: 'object #3'}}];

myArray.splice(myArray.findIndex(({state:{name}}) => name === "object #1"), 1);

console.log(myArray);
```